# PickPhotoAsync - the first time it doesn't work

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.essentials, montemagno-media.plugin

The first time I use the application after confirming the permission to access the photos saved on the gallery, pickphoto async seems to do nothing.
[image]

in my opinion the problem is that it does not wait for user authorization.

in order to work correctly I have to click on the upload button of the photo more than once.

i am working with android with the latest version of the library.

```
await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
{
    await DisplayAlert("Oops", "You Cannot pick an image", AppResources.Label_OK);
    return;
}
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new PickMediaOptions
{
    PhotoSize = PhotoSize.MaxWidthHeight,
    MaxWidthHeight = 800,
    SaveMetaData = false
});
```

Comment: First ensure you have `CAMERA`, `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions added to your AndroidManifest, also ensure to create the `file_provider` profile [check the Media Plugin Readme](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#android-required-setup) and by last i always checks for permissions after the `await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();` line and before execute the `PickPhotoAsync` and of course both initialization and pick are awaited.

Answer (score 0):

You could ask for the runtime permission before you load the page. After that, you do not need to click on the upload button of the photo more than once.

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    RunTimePermission();//ask for the runtime permission
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thank the people who answered me.
I found the error:

Wrong Code:

```
 public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
{
    PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

Correct code:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
{
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```